# Open New Tab When User Clicks on Link to External Website

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm developing a recommendations application written in React, and want the user to be able to be sent to external websites when the component containing the website's information has been clicked.

Currently, I have a wrapper that, when clicked, pushes the new URL to the history object from the React library. The source code is shown below.

```
<VStack onClick={() => history.push(<url here>)}> 
     <inside of component>
</VStack>
```

Unfortunately, the URL is being loaded in the same window, but I want the user to remain on the website, in the original tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your onClick function to

```
 onClick={() => window.open(urlHere)}
```

see more of window.open [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try setting the target attribute to "_blank" in the Link tag itself.

example:

```
<Link to="/somewhere" target="_blank">anything</Link>
```